# Get the date without the time of the selected value in rich:calendar

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I got a problem when using `rich:calendar`: after selecting the value, I am setting the value in the bean of type Calendar. In the bean it is showing an error and the date value is appeared along with the time so how can we get only date value without getting the time

Here is the code I have written:

```
<rich:calendar value="#{editCustomerBean.person.demographic.dateOfBirth}"
  cellWidth="15px" cellHeight="22px" style="width:200px"
  datePattern="yyyy,dd,MM"/>
```

The error message says:

```
SEVERE: //C:/Workspace/Kumar/WebContent/satish/Main.xhtml @71,268 
value="#{editCustomerBean.person.demographic.dateOfBirth}":   
Can't set property 'dateOfBirth' on   
class 'com.customer.types.Information' to value '7/11/12   
12:00   AM'.
```

When I set the value 2012,11,07 in the main page, I get the value `'7/11/12

    12:00   AM'` with an extra  `12:00   AM`.

How can I get only the date value?

Answer (score 1):

The message you are seeing with the value '7/11/12 12:00 AM' is not wrong, it is just the result of the `.toString()` method of the object date create by `rich:calendar`.

You should check if the class `com.customer.types.Information` (which from the message, it seems that is the type of the `editCustomerBean.person.demographic` property) actually has the appropriate `setDateOfBirth(Date dt)` method. Then, fix your code accordingly (pointing to the proper property or creating the adequate setter).

Comment: Thanks eljunior for ur reply I have proper getters and setters,Date of birth is of type calendar.I think it only accepts date and not time.So can i get only date but not time 12:00Am